# Accessing protected route

Tags: jquery, node.js, ajax, redirect, jwt

I just started using **JWT**. I do the **login** and I send the **token** as a **JSON response** to the **client**. Upon **successful login** I store that to **sessionStorage** and then I use that token to access the **protected route** through the headers of another **ajax call(GET)** which on success will redirect to that page.

I started by protecting **directly** the **route** I am **redirecting** too, and had **no** **/verify-user** **route** but since on **redirection** the **headers** are **not sent** I found this **solution** only for verifying the token. However I don't know if this is the good way.

What do you think?

My **login on the client**:

```
   // Login POST 
    $('#frm-login').submit(function (e) {
        event.preventDefault()
        $('button').text('Please wait ...').prop('disabled')
        $.ajax({
            url: "/login-user",
            type: "POST",
            data: $('#frm-login').serialize(),
            dataType: "json"
        }).always(function (response) {
            $('button').text('Logging in').prop('disabled')
            console.log("Login", response)
            if (response.status == "error") {
                $('button').removeClass('lime').addClass('red').text('Log in failed. Try again.');
                return
            }
            localStorage.setItem('token', response.token);
            console.log(localStorage.token)
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/verify-user",
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.token
                }
            }).always(function (response) {
                console.log("Access", response)
                if (response.status == "error") {
                    $('button').removeClass('lime').addClass('red').text('Log in failed. Try again.');
                    return
                }
                if (response.status == 301) {
                    $(location).attr('pathname', '/LIMELine/chatroom/');
                    //$('img#profile-img').attr('src', response.responseText.authData.user.avatar)
                    console.log(response)
                }
            });
        })
    })
```

My **login on the server**:

```
/********************* LOGIN *********************/

app.post('/login-user', (req, res) => {
    user.loginUser(req.body, (err, jResult) => {
        if (err) {
            return res.send(jResult)
        }
        let token = jwt.sign({
            user: jResult,
        }, "supersecret")
        console.log(token);
        return res.json({
            token: token
        })
        //add other headers here...
    })
})

/********************* VERIFY USER *********************/

app.get('/verify-user', verifyToken, (req, res) => {

    jwt.verify(req.token, "supersecret", (err, authData) => {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(403).json({
                message: "No token found"
            });
        }
        return res.status(301).json({
            authData
        });
    })
})
```

The **protected route**, which the user should see when logs in

```
// *********************   MAIN PAGE *********************************************

app.get('/LimeLINE/chatroom' (req, res) => {
            try {
            // CODE FOR CONTENT OF THE PAGE
            return res.json({
                authData
            });
        }
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are making a full page redirect (not through ajax but automatically through the browser, like when clicking an untempered anchor tag) the browser won't automatically send the `Authorization` HTTP header.

You can either start sending the JWT token using a cookie (which is less standard and ties the client to being a browser but will happen automatically on all full page and AJAX calls) or handle the redirect yourself through the ajax call.
Another "hybrid" solution would be to enable both `Authorization` header AND cookie as valid authorization methods.

IMO it all depends if your server should accept non browser client currently or in the near future.

Comment: how can I handle the ridirect through the ajax call ? isn´t that what I am doing right now?

Comment: @July333 Correct me if I'm wrong but upon getting a redirect code (301 - 303) you do something like change the `location` object? If not, please provide info on how the redirection is made

Comment: you mean a redirect code from the server ? right now I am only sending the token from the server and  redirect upon that.

Comment: Oh.. now see, you redirect using `window.location.pathname = '/LIMELine/chatroom'`, when the browser runs this code it performs a full page load upon which the `Authorization` header is not sent.

Comment: so how can perform a not full-page load?

Comment: It depends on your server and what kind of data it returns from `/LIMELine/chatroom`. I guess currently it returns an HTML page? if so, the JS code sending the Ajax would have to do a lot of ugly stuff to inject that HTML into your DOM (Ruby On Rails uses a library called Turbolinks that does just that).
The other approach would be to transfer the JWT token using a cookie instead of an HTTP header.

Comment: i could also make another route which would be protected and verifyToken there and all that stuff and then redirect to the /LIMELine/chatroom. how that sounds?

Comment: If I understand your intent correctly I'm afraid it won't work.. The problem is not in the route but rather in the way you contact the server. What about putting the JWT inside a cookie?

Comment: i don't think you do, I would just make that route to verify the token for my second ajax since when I redirect to /LIMELine/chatroom it gives me forbidden cause headers are not sent.

Comment: but that wouldn´t be a proper protection anymore i guess. I don´t know it that would be bad pratice

Comment: I just edited the code above with what I tried explaining, and it works, but I am not sure if this is a good practice.

Comment: Are you veryfing the JWT inside the route `/LimeLINE/chatroom`?

Comment: no, inside the /verify-user ? did you check the code above?

Comment: I understand, but how do you verify that `/LimeLINE/chatroom` is accessed by a verified user?